# Destination Folder must be accessible (Eclipse)

Tags: eclipse

When i Try to drag and drop a file into eclipse it gives me the error "Destination folder must be accessible." so i can't get it into my workspace. 
Can anyone help?

Comment: What is your destination folder? Does copy & past work? What operating system and which Eclipse version do you use?

Comment: I'm currently on Windows 10 64-bit and using Eclipse Oxygen. My destination folder is D:\WorkSP.

Comment: If the workspace is empty, first create a project: _File > New > Project..._. To open an existing project, use _File > Open Project from File System..._

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot drag and drop files into an empty workspace. You first need to create a project:

***File > New > Project...***

Or if you like to open a directory as a project:

***File > Open Projects from File System...***

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is correct, but it is not the only way of getting that error message.  For completeness sake, you can get "destination folder must be accessible" by:

1. Dragging the file into an empty Project Explorer.
   Solution: Create or import a project in the Project Explorer, then try again.
2. Dragging a file into a blank area in the Project Explorer.
   Solution: Drag the file onto a container, such as the project or a folder in the project.

Eclipse is part of the problem.  It accepts the drop only to display an error dialog.  It would of course be better if Eclipse provided feedback while dragging so unacceptable destination locations would display the appropriate mouse cursor (circle with a line through it) and not accept the drop.